# How to access React router history object with component interface that has default custom hook specified

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

I know how to access the router history object passed in props under many circumstances.  However, the syntax required with using a component interface that has a default custom hook is evading me.  Here is a snippet of the code:

```
interface LoginProps {
  useAuthHook?: () => {
    authUser: User
    loginStatus: string
    pwdChangeStatus: string
    isLoading: boolean
    error: string
  }
}

export function Login({ useAuthHook = useAuth, ...rest }: LoginProps) {
  const { authUser, loginStatus, pwdChangeStatus, error } = useAuthHook()
```

If I check the contents of rest using console.log and JSON.stringify, rest does contain the usual objects including history.  However, if I try using rest.history.push('/'), typescript complains that history is not part of rest.  I've tried declaring rest in the interface, but it doesn't work either.  I'm currently using useHistory as a bandaid to get around the problem, but would rather do this using the props.  Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All that is needed is to import RouteComponentProps from react-router-dom and use it as the base type for LoginProps as follows:

```
interface LoginProps extends RouteComponentProps {
  useAuthHook?: () => {
    authUser: User
    loginStatus: string
    pwdChangeStatus: string
    isLoading: boolean
    error: string
  }
}
```